# NODE.js Insert into SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection

I am trying to perform an `INSERT` into my SQL Server through my NODE.js server
but it is not working.

I believe it is not a connection problem because (as I will demonstrate at the end of the post) I did a select that worked, so I must be making some mistake in the node.js code.

This is the first javascript system I create.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    var sql = require("mssql");

             console.log("C1");
     sql.connect('mssql://login:pswd@serv/db', function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
         console.log("Connected!");
        var insert = "INSERT into dbo.WIDS_API_TEST (Programm, ID, Titlw) VALUES ('Teste 1 2 3 ', '39', 'Finance')"

        // query to the database and get the records
        sql.query(insert, function (err, result) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
        console.log("1 record inserted");

        });
    });
});

//var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
  //  console.log('Server is running..');
//});
```

What am I doing wrong? Because the INSERT did not even show my console.logs =/

When I performed a test doing a select it worked, so

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
/*    var config = {
        user: 'papercut',
        password: 'Portage.2018',
        server: 'devsqlcl2:1433', 
        database: 'AgrM6',
        port: "1433",
        dialect:",ssql",
        dialectOptiond:"SQLEXPRESS"
    };*/

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect('mssql://login:pswd@server:1433/database', function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from dbo.balance_papercut', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

This `SELECT` statement worked.